# Timestamp of current time change to 1970-01-20 after serialisation by Serialising Producer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, akhq

I've been the confluent-kafka[avro] (2.1.1) library to send the result of an AWS lambda to our kafka with an avro schema.

The serialisation of the schema is fine, except for the first key, "creation_time" which invariably is set to something like `1970-01-20T13:34:12.378Z` when received by kafka (as visualised in AKHQ).
The timestamp of the message is fine as long as I let it set to default, If y try to use the same timestamp as in the schema the message is shown in the AKHQ as sent 58 years ago.

I have the problem in all our environments kafka's and I can reproduce it on my local dev env.

I tried to debug the code, but I can't get info after the serialisation, here's what I'm sure of:
Timestamp var content just before serialisation (float): `1690451888.45323`
Time received on the AKHQ message: `1970-01-20T13:34:11.888Z`

After conversion this time give `1686851` as timestamp.
I initially through it was somehow truncated before serialisation, but it doesn't looks like it.

Here's how I get my timestamp in the values:

```py
timestamp = datetime.now(tz=tz.gettz(self.config.timezone)).timestamp()
values = {
    "creationTime": timestamp,
    "description": message,
    "eventTypeId": self.config.metric_name,
    "pgd": [],
    "contracts": [],
    "points": [],
    "objects": [],
}
```

My kafka code

```py
"""This module contains everything necessary to send messages to kafka"""
import logging

from confluent_kafka import SerializingProducer
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro import AvroSerializer
from confluent_kafka.serialization import StringSerializer

from param_store_models import KafkaInfo

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class KafkaProducer:
    """Class used to send messages to kafka"""

    def __init__(self, schema: str, kafka_info: KafkaInfo):
        producer_ssm_conf = {
            "bootstrap.servers": kafka_info.bootstrap_servers,
            "security.protocol": kafka_info.security_protocol,
            "sasl.mechanism": kafka_info.sasl_mecanism,
            "sasl.username": kafka_info.sasl_username,
            "sasl.password": kafka_info.sasl_password,
        }
        registry_ssm_conf = {"url": kafka_info.schema_registry_url}

        serializer = AvroSerializer(
            SchemaRegistryClient(registry_ssm_conf), schema, conf={"auto.register.schemas": False}
        )

        producer_default_conf = {
            "value.serializer": serializer,
            "key.serializer": StringSerializer(),
            "enable.idempotence": "true",
            "max.in.flight.requests.per.connection": 1,
            "retries": 5,
            "acks": "all",
            "retry.backoff.ms": 500,
            "queue.buffering.max.ms": 500,
            "error_cb": self.delivery_report,
        }

        self.__serializing_producer = SerializingProducer({**producer_default_conf, **producer_ssm_conf})

    def produce(self, topic: str, key=None, value=None, timestamp=0):
        """Asynchronously produce message to a topic"""
        LOGGER.info(f"Produce message {value} to topic {topic}")
        self.__serializing_producer.produce(topic, key, value, on_delivery=self.delivery_report, timestamp=timestamp)

    def flush(self):
        """
        Flush messages and trigger callbacks
        :return: Number of messages still in queue.
        """
        LOGGER.debug("Flushing messages to kafka")
        return self.__serializing_producer.flush()

    @staticmethod
    def delivery_report(err, msg):
        """
        Called once for each message produced to indicate delivery result.
        Triggered by poll() or flush().
        """
        if err:
            LOGGER.error(f"Kafka message delivery failed: {err}")
        else:
            LOGGER.info(f"Kafka message delivered to {msg.topic()} [{msg.partition()}]")
```

My avro schema (partially redacted to hide the customer info)

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "EventRecord",
  "namespace": "com.event",
  "doc": "Schéma d'un évènement de supervision brut",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "creationTime",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "eventTypeId",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "internalProductId",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "description",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "contracts",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": "string"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "points",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": "string"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "objects",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Received message on the akhq topic

```json
{
  "creationTime": "1970-01-20T13:34:12.378Z",
  "eventTypeId": "test",
  "description": "Test",
  "pgd": [],
  "contracts": [],
  "points": [],
  "objects": []
}
```

## Versions

confluent-kafka[avro]==2.1.1

kafka broker = latest

Operating system: Windows (Kafka stock on docker) / AWS ECS (Docker containers also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `timestamp` variable is created like so:

`timestamp = datetime.now(tz=tz.gettz(self.config.timezone)).timestamp()`

The `timestamp()` function you call returns the number of seconds since epoch. However, you are using the `timestamp-millis` logical type which expects milliseconds since epoch.

So the easiest solution is just to multiple your `timestamp` by 1000.

Another option is that most libraries support logical types so that you should be able to set the `creationTime` to the datetime object and the library will do the conversion to figure out how many milliseconds it should be for serialization.

Comment: Thanks! That was my first time using kafka/avro i didn't notice the millis...
I tested it with just giving iut the datetime object and the timestamp conversion is automatic, received time was correcct after that :)